# JavaScript if statement with extra condition

Tags: javascript, jquery-calculation

I have a JavaScript `if` statement that does the following:

If a payment method called cardless is chosen, then the cardfee varable is set to be 1% of the total fee.

```
if (document.getElementById('payment_method').value == "Cardless") {
    cardfee = ((thetotal * (1 + vatrate)) * 0.01);    
}    
document.getElementById('card_fee').value = cardfee;    
formatPrice(document.getElementById('card_fee'));
```

The problem is that while the 1% of the total fee is fine, the payment method has a cap. Its 1% but a maximum of £2.

How would I make it do the calculation above, but then add another line that says if cardfee is greater than £2, set cardfee to £2?

Comment: `if (cardfee > 2) { cardfee = 2; }` ?

Comment: just a little note, and maybe you know this, but if there are actual monetary implications to what the client chooses, you shouldn't be doing it client side. A user could alter that and submit a lower amount for processing. Ensure you have server-side rules in place as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change the conditional, you can just change how you assign the new value.  [Using `Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) you can assign it to the lesser of two values:

```
if (document.getElementById('payment_method').value == "Cardless") {
    cardfee = Math.min(((thetotal * (1 + vatrate)) * 0.01), 2.0);
}
```

That way if the resulting calculation is greater than `2.0`, the assignment will be to `2.0`.  Otherwise, the assignment will be to the calculation result.  (If the two are equal, then it doesn't matter which one is used.)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the second statment to the inside of your `if` block

```
if (document.getElementById('payment_method').value == "Cardless") {
  cardfee = ((thetotal * (1 + vatrate)) * 0.01);
  if (cardfee > 2.0) {
    cardfee = 2.0
  }
}
document.getElementById('card_fee').value = cardfee;
formatPrice(document.getElementById('card_fee'));
```